# Переклад англійського фразеологізму "There are spots even on the Sun"

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми

Фразеологізм "There are spots even on the Sun" вживається для того, щоб дати зрозуміти, що кожен має право на помилку, що нічого нема ідеального (тобто мається на увазі, що навіть на самому Сонці є плями (воно не ідеальне), що вже й говорити про щось інше). Ось [приклад](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Va48DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=%22There%20are%20spots%20even%20on%20the%20Sun%22&source=bl&ots=kKMFTz0U4J&sig=dnIcrWgowyg2pBNLr5Wou4HzcBU&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJyLLE6JXfAhUPAhAIHZYNAUQQ6AEwCHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22There%20are%20spots%20even%20on%20the%20Sun%22&f=false):

> "There are spots even on the Sun, and I am no Sun" - "Навіть на Сонці
>   є плями, а я ж не Сонце".

Дослівний переклад ([Гугл](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=uk&text=There%20are%20spots%20even%20on%20the%20Sun) перекладає також так) буде: "Навіть на Сонці є плями". Однак, мені здається, що ми можемо знайти влучний український відповідник. І, перш за все, цікавить чи не може фразеологізм "І кінь на чотирьох ногах спотикається" бути таким (однак, в такому випадку переклад речення із тексту буде дещо комічним - "І кінь на чотирьох ногах спотикається, а я ж не кінь")? Чи можливо є кращі варіанти?

Comment: Трішки off-topic, але мені не подобається оте «ж» в «а я ж не Сонце / не кінь», бо воно, мені здається, не передає вкладеного сенсу, мовляв, «мені далеко до Сонця / куди мені до коня з його 4 ногами». Я б сказав «навіть не Сонце / не кінь», а якщо не хочете повторювати «навіть», то я б ужив «й» («а я й не…»), а не «ж». У випадку коня, до речі, можна сказати («а в мене всього дві» замість «а я… не кінь»).

Comment: @Sasha, і спрадві хорошим варіантом може бути "І кінь на чотирьох ногах спотикається, а в мене їх всього дві"! Про це я якось не подумав, дякую!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нещодавно наткнувся на такі слова у книзі "Сага про...":

> "І на Сонці є плями, а ми - живі люди".

Після чого я подумав, що можливо в українській мові є вислів "і на Сонці є плями". І на сайті [Російсько-українського словника](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/i) мені справді вдалося знайти такий переклад (хоча більше ніде не вдалося знайти такий вислів і тому не впевнений у 100% достовірності того, що це не калька):

> "И на солнце есть (бывают) пятна"  - "І на сонці є (бувають) плями".

І беручи до уваги поради із коментарів я зробив висновок, що друга частина не обов'язково має бути дослівним перекладом, тому отримав такий варіант:

**"І на Сонці є плями, а я ж лише людина".**

І гадаю, що можливий варіант запропонований у коментарях:

**"І кінь на 4-ох ногах спотикається, а у мене їх всього дві".**